# ReactJS SyntheticEvent stopPropagation() only works with React events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to use event.stopPropagation() within a ReactJS component to stop a click event from bubbling up and triggering a click event that was attached with JQuery in legacy code, but it seems like React's stopPropagation() only stops propagation to events also attached in React, and JQuery's stopPropagation() doesn't stop propagation to events attached with React.

Is there any way to make stopPropagation() work across these events?  I wrote a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LEDT/3/) to demonstrate these behaviors:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Propagation = React.createClass({
    alert: function(){
        alert('React Alert');
    },
    stopPropagation: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.alert}>
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.stopPropagation}>React Stop Propagation on React Event</a>
                </div>
                <div className="alert">
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.stopPropagation}>React Stop Propagation on JQuery Event</a>
                </div>
                <div onClick={this.alert}>
                    <a href="#" className="stop-propagation">JQuery Stop Propagation on React Event</a>
                </div>
                <div className="alert">
                    <a href="#" className="stop-propagation">JQuery Stop Propagation on JQuery Event</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Propagation />, document.body);

$(function(){    
    $(document).on('click', '.alert', function(e){
        alert('Jquery Alert');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.stop-propagation', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: React's actual event listener is also at the root of the document, meaning the click event has already bubbled to the root. You can use `event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation` to prevent other event listeners from firing, but order of execution is not guaranteed.

Comment: Actually, [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation) claims event listeners will be called in the order in which they were bound. If your React JS is initialized before your jQuery (as it is in your fiddle), stopping immediate propagation will work.

Comment: React stopping jQuery listeners from being called: http://jsfiddle.net/7LEDT/5/ It's not possible for jQuery to prevent React from being called because jQuery listeners are bound later in your fiddle.

Comment: One option would be to set up your own jQuery event handler in `componentDidMount`, but it might interfere with other React event handlers in unexpected ways.

Comment: I realized the second example on `.stop-propagation` necessarily will not work. Your example uses event delegation but is trying to stop propagation at the element. The listener needs to be bound to the element itself: `$('.stop-propagation').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`. This fiddle prevents all propagation like you were trying: http://jsfiddle.net/7LEDT/6/

Comment: I had similar problem and solved it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/25862475/679340

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/e59f6eca03da7c1960013cc94e04e84f

Answer (score 195, accepted):

React uses event delegation with a single event listener on `document` for events that bubble, like 'click' in this example, which means stopping propagation is not possible; the real event has already propagated by the time you interact with it in React. `stopPropagation` on React's synthetic event is possible because React handles propagation of synthetic events internally.

#### Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LEDT/6/) with the fixes from below.

#### React Stop Propagation on jQuery Event

Use [`Event.stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation) to prevent your other (jQuery in this case) listeners on the root from being called. It is supported in IE9+ and modern browsers.

```
stopPropagation: function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
},
```

- *Caveat: Listeners are called in the order in which they are bound. React must be initialized before other code (jQuery here) for this to work.*

#### jQuery Stop Propagation on React Event

Your jQuery code uses event delegation as well, which means calling `stopPropagation` in the handler is not stopping anything; the event has already propagated to `document`, and React's listener will be triggered.

```
// Listener bound to `document`, event delegation
$(document).on('click', '.stop-propagation', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

To prevent propagation beyond the element, the listener must be bound to the element itself:

```
// Listener bound to `.stop-propagation`, no delegation
$('.stop-propagation').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Edit (2016/01/14):** Clarified that delegation is necessarily only used for events that bubble. For more details on event handling, React's source has descriptive comments: [ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabd/packages/react-dom/src/events/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js#L52-L85).

Comment: @ssorellen: Clarification: does React bind its event listener on `document`, or the root React component? The [linked page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation) just says "at the top level", which I take to mean that it *not* the `document` (but I can't figure out if this is even relevant).

Comment: @FighterJet That depends on the event type. For events that bubble, top-level delegation is used. For events that don't bubble, React necessarily listens on various DOM nodes. A more thorough description is included in ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b96650e39ddda5ba49245713ef16dbc52d25e9e/src/renderers/dom/client/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js#L23

Comment: Also check out Jim's answer, which suggests adding the global click listener to `window` instead of `document`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879137/438273

Comment: "stopPropagation on React's synthetic event is possible because React handles propagation of synthetic events internally." I am trying to find a webpage that explains this part in details, found nothing yet, can someone provide a link if there is one? thanks!

Answer (score 24):

It is still one intersting moment:

```
ev.preventDefault()
ev.stopPropagation();
ev.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Use this construction, if your function is wrapped by tag

Comment: `event.nativeEvent` is the correct answer; I was able to use `composedPath()` by way of it: `event.nativeEvent.composedPath()`

Comment: What do you mean `wrapped by tag`? could you pls provide an example?

Comment: @JimmyLv I mean 
`<div onClick=(firstHandler)>
<div onClick=(secHandler)>active text</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 22):

Worth noting (from [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4335)) that if you're attaching events to `document`, `e.stopPropagation()` isn't going to help. As a workaround, you can use `window.addEventListener()` instead of `document.addEventListener`, then `event.stopPropagation()` will stop event from propagating to the window.

Answer (score 10):

From the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events):
The event handlers below are **triggered** by an event **in the bubbling phase**. To register an event handler for the capture phase, **append Capture**. (emphasis added)

If you have a click event listener in your React code and you don't want it to bubble up, I think what you want to do is use `onClickCapture` instead of `onClick`. Then you would pass the event to the handler and do `event.nativeEvent.stopPropagation()` to keep the native event from bubbling up to a vanilla JS event listener (or anything that's not react).

Comment: Thank you, that's what worked for me as of 2021 and React 17. onClickCapture={e => e.stopPropagation()} was enough though, didn't have to use event.nativeEvent to stop propagation to the root.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following to my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: This will stop SynteticEvents altogether, because React uses event delegation with a single event listener on document for events that bubble.

Answer (score 7):

React 17 delegates events to `root` instead of `document`, which might solve the problem.
More details [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html).
You can also refer to [my blog](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/react-17-delegates-events-to-root-instead-of-document).

Comment: Some months ago I had a listener on document that would still receive a mousedown event even after `event.stopPropagation()` was called (and I relied on this behavior), but noticed that it stopped getting called after I updated a lot of libraries. I suspected the cause was the update of ReactJS, and your answer now confirms/explains it.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem yesterday, so I created a React-friendly solution.

Check out [react-native-listener](https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-native-listener). It's working very well so far. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: `react-native-listener` uses `findDomNode` which will be deprecated
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220

Comment: Downvoted because answers are not an appropriate place to market or deliver external solutions which do not complement a complete answer.

Answer (score 4):

A quick workaround is using `window.addEventListener` instead of `document.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Update: You can now `<Elem onClick={ proxy => proxy.stopPropagation() } />`

Comment: See @RossAllen's answer. This will not prevent propagation to an ancestor's native DOM listeners (which jQuery uses).

Comment: Well this is the right way if you're using a react component. Highjacking the event isn't a good idea.

Comment: If something else is failing, it's because you're doing something else wrong

Comment: I agree that that is the correct way if all your listeners are attached via React, but that is not the question here.

Comment: That's just me... I will always encourage correct use of the correct way instead of leading somebody astray with a work around that may cause them grief in the future because they have a 'solution' to a problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `e.stopPropagation()` didn't work because child had `onChange` event, parent `onClick`. Got insight from [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39915582/5646315)

> The change and click events are different events.

Meagning:
`e.stopPropagation()` calling inside `onChange` won't prevent firing `onClick`.

Solution to have both onChange or onClick.

Answer (score 1):

The way i've solved this is by adding an *if* statement at the callback that check the `event.target` and if its diferent to the element i expect, then return from the function

```js
// Callback from my own app
function exitResultsScreen(event){
        // Check element by ID
        if (event.target.className !== sass.div__search_screen){return} 
        
       // Executed only when the right elements calls
        setShowResults(false)
}
```