# How can I add a click handler to BODY from within a React component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a pulldown menu React component that should close when the user clicks anywhere in the DOM **outside** of the component.

Using jQuery I would typically add an event listener to the `body` when the pulldown is opened, and remove it again when the pulldown is closed. (The event listener itself closes the pulldown – any click events **within** the component are not propagated to prevent the body click handler from firing.)

Is there any way to attach a listener to the `body` element from within a React component? Or should I just use jQuery? (I'm a bit wary of mixing React and jQuery.)

Comment: Can't you just use the DOM? Like this: `document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) { // handled! })`

Comment: I would try componentDidMount then inside that use comment above suggestion.Edit - what @limelights said ;)

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component

Answer (score 40, accepted):

React is just JavaScript so attaching a click handler to any element is done as normal by using `addEventListener()`. Doing this in `componentDidMount` is normally very nice and tidy and clean up after yourself in `componentWillUnmount` by removing the added event handler.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.myHandler);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.myHandler);
    },
    myHandler: function () {
        alert('click');
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: OK. Works as advertised. The only (new) problem is that stopping propagation in JS on the DOM element also prevents React events being fired in child elements, that should receive the event first. Due to React events being delegated from `document`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24421834/698511

Comment: Unfortunately I've noticed that this solution may indeed result in trouble depending on your use case. In order to stay within the React events realm, I'll opt for managing app state at the top level within React and the appropriate use of `shouldComponentUpdate` to avoid excessive re-rendering of unrelated components to the action.

Answer (score 8):

It's help who used function based components:

```
import React, { useEffect  } from 'react';

const ZSideBar = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', closeSidemenu );

        return function cleanup() {
            window.removeEventListener('click', closeSidemenu );
        } 
    },[]);
    let closeSidemenu = () => {
        document.getElementById("sidebar-tree").style.left = "-310px";
    }
   
    return (
        <div></div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Won't the "closeSidemenu" function run on load of component too ?