# How does one stop propagation of event to a global listener in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, event-handling, event-delegation

I have a component that should listen all mousedown events on my page

`document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener)`

Now let's suppose I have a button in my React app

```
<button 
  onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}
  onClick={e => doSomething()}
/>
```

Using `onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}` will not prevent my global mousedown listener to be triggered, because React uses event delegation (I suppose?)

The only way to make it work is to call `onMouseDown={e => e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()}`

Is there any way to make this more natural from a developer perspective? I mean it's not very convenient to have to explain to everyone of a large team why regular e.stopPropagation() does not work, how event delegation works etc...

So, is there anything I can do so that when calling `e.stopPropagation()` it actually does not trigger my main mousedown listener?

Is there a supported way, from my listener, to filter events on which `stopPropagation` was called (by React or not?)

Is there a way to change the node on which React handle the delegated events? (it seems to be `document` here)

Comment: Have you seen this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/24415631/5157454?

Comment: yes it just explains how event delegation works but does not give a solution to my problem

Comment: I would also like to know what are the best practices for using events to the document in React