# Button onClick return inner html instead of value in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-browser

I have different behavior on `firefox` and `chrome` for the bellow code, and i think `firefox` is more correct.

`firefox` will print on the `console`:

```
<button value="2" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton">
```

while `chrome` will print this:

```
<i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
```

here is my code:

```
<button value={props.value} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onClick(e);
}}>
    <i className="material-icons">{props.icon}</i>
</button>


onClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid cross browser issues, best solution is to pass the value to the click handler function instead of the event itself.

```
<button value={props.value} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onClick(props.value);
}}>
    <i className="material-icons">{props.icon}</i>
</button>


onClick(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` will give you the last leaf of clicked DOM  , in your example , can be `<button />` as can be one of its children namely `<i />`.

In the following example , try  :

1. to click at the corner of button   e.target === `button`
2. to click in the middle of the button  e.target === `i`

[image]

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button value={this.props.value} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button-icon" onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.props.onClick(e);
}}>
    <i className="material-icons">{this.props.icon}</i>
</button>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App icon="click me" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target)} />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```css
.mdl-button {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height:  40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably find what you are looking for here:  [ReactJS SyntheticEvent stopPropagation() only works with React events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events)

Comment: same behaviour still?