# Event is propagating to parent even if the event.stopPropagation is written in onClick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, href

In the below code When clicked on settings the page is redirected to `google.com` even the `e.stopPropagation` is written in setting's `onClick` handler

```
    <a className="App" href="http://google.com" onClick={() => alert("parent")}>
      Home
      <div
        href={"http://youtube.com"}
        onClick={e => {
          alert("child");
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}
      >
        Settings
      </div>
    </a>
```

Why is that? But When I add `e.preventDefault()` it is not redirecting to `google.com` ? Why `e.stopPropagation` not working and `e.preventDefault` is working.Can anyone explain.

sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/l7wx5yzp6m

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events) may help you.

Comment: If you don't want the page to redirect either use `e.preventDefault` or `return false;` in your function.

Comment: Hello I tried the sandbox and I was not redirected.

Comment: @AlejandroDG please try the direct sandbox preview link https://l7wx5yzp6m.codesandbox.io/, for some reason in the sandbox preview the link is not redirecting.

Comment: @AdamH But why `e.preventDefault()`? `e.stopPropagation` must stop the event from propagating the event from child to parent right?

Comment: Yes, the event won't be propagated using `e.stopPropagation` but the default event for a link is to redirect to that link, so if you don't want the default action taken then you need to `e.preventDeault`.

Comment: @AdamH Yes, that makes sense. Thanks.