# not assignable type for event listener

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a TypeScript React component that has an event listener. However, when I do so, I get the following error message:

> TS2345: Argument of type '(event: React.MouseEvent) =>
>   void' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.

[image]

Am I missing a certain type check? Thanks. You can see the component code below.

**sampleComponent.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface MyState {
  onClick: boolean;
}

export default class SampleComponent extends React.Component<{}, MyState> {
  private divRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  public constructor() {
    super({});
    this.state = {
      onClick: false,
    };
    this.divRef = React.createRef();
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  public handleClickOutside(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void {
    if (
      this.divRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
    ) {
      this.setState({ onClick: true });
    }
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement {
    return (
      <div ref={this.divRef}>
        { this.state.onClick ? 'Foo' : 'Bar' }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

#### tldr

Change the `handleClickOutside` event type from `React.MouseEvent` to native `MouseEvent`:

```
public handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent): void { ... }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgFkBPAZRhTrgG9ycOBGoBhADbA0AawBccAEYQI41NQoBfSkgAekWHAAmSRgFdx8NOJQBnG3A4pwq0bkjUktOLrrVD95HQYADpXcBFPGAAePg0AGlZObjoAPn5KITBTBUk0ODQ3CNoAEWBDFghTWgAKAEp5ADcIMvShIUMINFMQSOCUQ0MAUQbIgBlgG196aoByEEqbJA6Ad2oZhJgACwngzZQ-F1zpAHlTGBsypFqKIS1BOD2DpAkpE7OL4zgAXjhqpBHaPIKqZFsNIvU4E0Wl80nw4FohAB6RFwIhgaxoZgKNhwQDJhHAYBACVBgABzUn0bxQHBQOAoUkoGj3ZEPfaGQ6vU7nS7fX7-SLyQIYYLA0EA6IACQAKixRoNVD1aCkIVDDN9YfCMnAsjkpKjPMYoHVWm0iDBTFBqHAooZgA0UphlFFEbb7fctBogA)

---

#### More infos

Event types on React elements differ from event types on "conventional" DOM elements.

React has its own [synthetic](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) [event handling system](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). E.g. [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) is used and a single event listener installed on `document` for events that bubble. This deviation is reflected in the types.

```
const MyComp = () => <div onClick={handleClick}></div>
```

creates following signature for [`onClick`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f0016483a4b1d1fd6fd636c47eea19e2d1614336/types/react/index.d.ts#L1213):

```
/**
 * React.MouseEvent = SyntheticEvent type from React
 * MouseEvent = native DOM event type
 */
(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void
```

The callback type for a directly added click listener to the DOM via [`document.addEventListener`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4981) is:

```
listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any
```

Related: [ReactJS SyntheticEvent stopPropagation() only works with React events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events)

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense because creating an `addEventListener` happens outside of react, or at least the event being passed from the listener is native.