# Stop propagation of Material UI TextField events from other keydown handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, material-ui

In my React app, I cannot stop propagation of keyboard events from Material UI TextField.

Example of the problem - pressing the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key inside the textfield triggers a delete operation in my authoring environment.

On change in the Material UI component:

```
<TextField onChange={handleChange} />
```

I try to stop propagation:

```js
const handleChange = event => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ...
};
```

But this does not stop my other event listener from firing:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

const onKeyDown = event => {
  switch (event.code) {
    case "Backspace":
    case "Delete":
      // ...
      break;
}
```

Ultimately not a big deal as I can change the scope of my keydown listener from `document` to the `canvas` element it's intended to work with, but curious if there was a suggestion here.

Comment: I think using `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();` in onKeyDown handler would work but I am not sure TextField exposes that. I think this other question is relevant to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events

Comment: Yep e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by adding the following `onKeyDown` event in TextField Tag.

```
<TextField onChange={handleChange} onKeyDown={e=>{ e.stopPropagation()}} />
```