# Why event propagates to parent even after calling e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, browser

I have made a *Sidepanel* component in *React* and have attached a click listener to close the panel when user clicks anywhere outside the Sidepanel component, like so:

```
function Sidepanel({ isOpen, children }) {
  const [isPanelOpen, setPanelOpen] = useState(isOpen);
  const hidePanel = () => setPanelOpen(false);
 
  ... 

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', hidePanel);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', hidePanel);
    };
  });

  return (
    <aside
      className={`side-panel ${isPanelOpen ? 'side-panel--open' : ''}`} 
      onClick={stopEventPropagation}
    >
      <div className="side-panel__body">{children}</div>
    </aside>
  );
}

function stopEventPropagation (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // <-- DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
};

export default Sidepanel;
```

But, this code doesn't work as expected since the panel starts to close on a click even inside the `<aside>` element itself. It seemed like `e.stopPropagation()` did nothing so I updated the `stopEventPropagation` code to:

```
function stopEventPropagation (e) {
  e.nativeEvent && e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
};
```

...which also didn't work. But, when I did this:

```
function stopEventPropagation (e) {
  e.nativeEvent && e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); // <- IT WORKED!
};
```

...it worked. Weird!

I read some docs about *stopImmediatePropagation* I found on Google and realised that although it makes the code work, it just doesn't make any sense here. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events
This will probably answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Replace `document.addEventListener` by `window.addEventListener` so that `event.stopPropagation()` can stop event propagate to window.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you please add more detail about why this should work?

Comment: You can find the details if you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events). You can check [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4335) as well.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, we are talking about the term `Event bubbling` (or `Bubbling` for short). So make sure you have knowledge about it, otherwise, please take a look at this [article](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

In the above article, you may find this useful [one](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#stopping-bubbling):

**If an element has multiple event handlers on a single event, then even if one of them stops the bubbling, the other ones still execute.**

**1. `event.stopPropagation()` stops the move upwards, but on the current element all other handlers will run.**

**2. To stop the bubbling and prevent handlers on the current element from running, there’s a method `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. After it no other handlers execute.**

Back to your problem, it belongs to the later case. You have two `onClick` handlers attached to `document`, so using `event.stopPropagation()` is not the case here, but `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

---Update 1:

React (currently) uses a listener on the `document` for (almost) all events, so by the time your component receives the event it has already bubbled all the way up to the `document`.

That means, the later `onClick` handler which is attached to the `aside` element will bubble up to `document`.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the event listener normally (by `window.addEventListener()`) then `e.stopPropagation()` should work. But if you added it via React (by `onClick`) then it won't work, because React uses its own event processing which itself listens on `document`. So by the time the `onClick` handler on `aside` runs, the event may have been bubbled up and reached `document`, where your `hidePanel()` listener fired.

`e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` might cancel all listeners before that happens and solve your problem, but blindly bypassing event handlers (possibly added by some UI library) might cause side effects. So a better approach that is not affected by all the confusing event propagation, might be handling the logic within the `document click` listener.

```js
    const hidePanel = (e) => {
        // Only hide panel if clicked outside it
        if (!e.target.classList.contains('side-panel')) {
            setPanelOpen(false);
        }
    }
```