# Ag-Grid Prevent onRowClicked event when clicking icon inside cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a cell renderer that returns the name property and objects on a row:

```
const nameRenderer = ({ value, data }) => {
    const { id: queueId } = data;
    return (
      <Box>
        <div className="row-hidden-menu">
            <IconButton
              icon="menu"
              onClick={({ event }) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                onMenuClick();
              }}
            />
        </div>
      </Box>
    );
  };
```

[image]

The issue I have is that I have an `onRowClick` function but I don't want that function to be called when I click the icon from the `nameRenderer`. Right now when the menu opens, the `onRowClicked` event navigates to a new page.

Comment: prevent default should stop event bubbling

Comment: @sandeepjoshi your assumption is wrong. `stopPropagation()` will stop the event from bubbling up  while `preventDefault()` will only surpress the default behavior of the event. The code provided in the question is in the right direction but it doesn't work because of a React design quirk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24421834/9449426) for more in-depth explanation, but the gist is that the `event` that you receive from the `onClick` callback is React's synthetic event which is a wrapper of the native event. Calling `stopPropagation()` from a synthetic event will not stop the real event from bubbling up and it is a quirk of the React framework for a long time.

Solution: attach your `onClick` event handler to the real DOM element instead.

```js
function ButtonCellRenderer() {
  return (
    <button
      ref={(ref) => {
        if (!ref) return;

        ref.onclick = (e) => {
          console.log("native event handler");
          e.stopPropagation(); // this works
          // put your logic here instead because e.stopPropagation() will
          // stop React's synthetic event
        };
      }}
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation(); // this doesn't work
      }}
    >
      Click me
    </button>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63964553/ag-grid-prevent-onrowclicked-event-when-clicking-icon-inside-cell]

Answer (score 0):

There is also workaround with `preventDefault()`

Inside cell you might have code like this:

```
<div
  onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
>
 <Button />
</div>
```

And use original handler:

```
<AgGrid 
  onRowClicked={(row) => {
    if(row.event.defaultPrevented) {
      return null
    }

    doSomethingHere()
  }}
/>
```