# How does stopPropagation possibly work under event delegation at root in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just started out learning React, and there is something that confuses me for quite some time regarding event handling.

it looks a paradox to me:

1. event delegation at root: event handler functions are called/attached at root level, not at the target component in which its triggered.
2. stopPropagation will stop the event from being bubbled up.

here comes the confusing part:

if we call stopPropagation in the eventHandler function for any of the component under root, that event won't/shouldn't even reach root because of 2, in that case, that handler function shouldn't/won't be called in the first place since all the handler functions are attached to the root level(because of 1).

I am sure I misunderstand something, just not sure what it is.

The proposed answer in the other post did not fully explain this.

Simply put, if we add a click eventHandler to both button and container element, then we add stopPropagation to the one belonging to the button. Container handler SHOULD not be triggered. But according to "event delegation at root", by the time the event reaches the handler for the button thru bubbling, it already passed container, which makes stopPropagation useless, for all the element below react root. (still works for the ones above though)

```html
<root>
  <container>
    <button />
   </container>
</root>
```

Comment: or better [ReactJS SyntheticEvent stopPropagation() only works with React events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events) which describes exactly your question

Comment: @pilchard yes, I am trying to find a link that can explain this sencence in details though: "stopPropagation on React's synthetic event is possible because React handles propagation of synthetic events internally."

Comment: You can read through the code itself, the comments are very descriptive: [SyntheticBaseEvent#stopPropagation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/events/SyntheticEvent.js#L105)